# How to open ConEmu on the screen where my mouse is?

Tags: conemu

On multiple screen, Yakuake has this amazing option to open "At mouse position", when it's activated and you're opening Yakuake with whatever shortcut you have, Yakuake display on the screen you left your mouse on.

ConEmu always open on the same screen, wherever is your mouse.

Is there a way to show ConEmu on the current screen i am working on ?

[image]

as the image shows, I want it to open on screen 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A windows programmer *COULD* make their app open wherever the mouse is but that is not a feature of the operating system.  ConEmu does not do this.. in fact, I am aware of no other KDE or Windows app that does this.  The ConEmu source code is free.  You can make this happen yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the option for that, go to settings and check :

1. General > "Quake-style slide down form the top of the screen"
2. General > Size&Pos > "Restore to active Monitor"